# Excel VBA: Fetch Google Map latitude, longitude by clicking

Tags: excel, google-maps, vba

This I have done: I have to show the google map in Excel or Browser by using a address or location or latitude and longitude by showing it in IE or default browser and I tried in MS web browser component in excel but that is opening in compatibility mode. I tried with Microsoft power map that required some installation.

I need help on: from the opened map I need to select location/address I need the latitude and longitude value to be update in my excel sheet.

In addition to that simple way, I need to send latitude and longitude to google map and same time I need receive latitude and longitude from map by clicking the map. in excel web browser no scripts are running.

Comment: Please add further requirements to the question via the 'edit' function and not to the comments. After having done that, please delete your comment (and flag mine to be 'obsolete' OR let me delete it myself).

Comment: You should also provide the code you have already tried. SO is not a macro writing service but will be happy to help if you can show you have made a reasonable attempt to complete the work yourself.

Comment: I have removed your urgent begging for a second time, and this time I've downvoted and cast a close vote. Note that transferring your urgency to volunteers here does not go down well, and for good reason. People may get around to your (good, specific) questions at their leisure.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you'll have to overcome two obstacles:

1. Find an Event on the WebBrowser control that fires when the browser
   is loaded with a new URL.
2. Parse the Lat and Long from the URL

Thankfully, Google's newer Map's URL are super friendly for parsing... AND Microsoft's WebBrowser control has some nice hooks built in.

You probably have some code that looks something like:

```
Sub webbrowsergo()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate2 ("https://www.google.com/maps/@39.1240533,-79.8562553,16z")
End Sub
```

That will send the web browser control to somewhere in West Virginia, I think.

Now, in your WorkSheet's VBA code, you can use the `WebBrowser_NavigateComplete2` event to hook in. This event will fire once a URL has completely loaded. Like if anyone moves the map or changes the zoom.

In your Worksheet's VBA code, hit the first drop down box at the top of the VBE and choose your WebBrowser control (probably named `WebBrowser1` or something). Then in the second drop down box, find the `NavigateComplete2` event.

It looks something like:

[image]

Your VBE will make a new sub for you and you can add the following:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Navigation complete, URL=" & URL

    Dim strLat As String, strLong As String

    strLat = Split(URL, "@")(1)
    strLat = Split(strLat, ",")(0)

    strLong = Split(URL, ",")(1)

    Debug.Print strLat, strLong        
End Sub
```

So, pretty simple stuff. We use the `Navigate2Complete` event of the `WebBrowser` control which fires every time the WebControl updates, and has this nice parameter called `URL` which contains the URL that was just loaded to the WebBrowser control. We use `Split()` to parse it and grab the Lat and Long.

`Debug.Print` just writes out the variables to your VBE's Immediate window. Go to View>>Immediate Window to turn that on if you don't have it already. Obviously, you can change that to push the Lat and Long to a worksheet or something.

Comment: Thanks lot for your response. Already I have tried the same its working fine. I struck here, I need the Lat and Long value in excel when I click on the map. I may click randomly any were in the map that Log and Long should be updated in my excel sheet. I need help here...

Comment: Then you'll need to write or find a web service that displays a map and then updates the url when the user merely clicks on it. If you've already done the above, I would expect that you would add that to your question above so folks could see that you've tried it. Please, if you continue to use StackOverflow, try just a little hard to make it so we don't have to guess at what you want.